# How do I send "origin" as the referrer for the favicon.ico file when clicking on an image?

Tags: http, nginx, header, refer

I have a simple image preview that, when clicked, takes you to a full size image:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="referrer" content="origin">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/myimage.jpg">
      <img src="/myimage.jpg" title="my image" border="0" />
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem: in addition to the request for the image, the browser will also request the favicon.ico. The request headers for the image is: `Referer: https://example.com/` (as expected). However, for the request for the favicon.ico file, this header is the full url of the referring page:  `Referer: https://example.com/where-I-was`.

How do I set the Referer header for the favicon.ico request to simply the origin? I don't want it the full url to show in my nginx logs. Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Use the `referrerpolicy` HTML attribute on the link tag - [see docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy#Integration_with_HTML).

```
<a href="/myimage.jpg" referrerpolicy="origin">
```

**Option 2**

Use the `webRequest` API to rewrite the Referer header - [see the MDN page on it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests#Modifying_request_headers). Simply set the header to whatever you want it to be - seems like you might be interested in the [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) object.

Sample code - modified from the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Intercept_HTTP_requests#Modifying_request_headers):

```
var targetURL = "http://example.com/favicon.ico";

var protocol = window.location.protocol;
var hostname = window.location.hostname;
var port = window.location.port;

var origin = protocol + '//' + hostname + (port ? ':' + port : '');

function rewriteUserAgentHeader(e) {
  e.requestHeaders.forEach(function(header){
    if (header.name.toLowerCase() == "referer") {
      header.value = origin;
    }
  });
  return {requestHeaders: e.requestHeaders};
}

browser.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
  rewriteUserAgentHeader,
  {urls: [targetURL]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

Comment: I think that might do it. Can you please add a complete example to help people in the future?

Comment: Option 1 isn't going to work since that would only apply to the image itself and not the favicon.

Comment: Just added sample for option 2. Haven't had a chance to test, but I suspect it works - please let me know if not!

Comment: Hm shouldn't option 1 apply to all requests made from that link?

Comment: Option #2 gives: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'webRequest' of undefined
    at my.js:12

Comment: Yeah, I tested them both myself and saw the same :( seems like option two link is from a browser extension; I somehow managed to miss that the first time I read it - sorry about that!

Comment: At this point I'm wondering if there's a way to not log it on the Nginx side? Maybe have a `location` block for favicon.ico and rewrite the `referer` header there? IIRC Nginx only logs upon successful completion of the request, not upon receipt of the request